# Refactor multiple if statments

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a method that includes 14 if statements and I Have to do the exact same thing 12 more times so like 160 if statements. How can I refactor to make this cleaner? I am working with a telerik radgrid and I am apply conditional formatting to the cells but it is different for each column and different depending on a value in a different column. here is the beginning of my method.

fyi: it does work.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Is it a GridDataItem
        if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            //Get the instance of the right type
            GridDataItem dataBoundItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;

            //Check the formatting condition
            if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "4hr YP")
            {
                if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem["ph"].Text) > 5.72 || float.Parse(dataBoundItem["ph"].Text) < 4.75)
                {
                    dataBoundItem["ph"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    dataBoundItem["ph"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    dataBoundItem["ph"].Font.Bold = true;

                }
                if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem["brix"].Text) > 22.36 || float.Parse(dataBoundItem["brix"].Text) < 17.35)
                {
                    dataBoundItem["brix"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    dataBoundItem["brix"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    dataBoundItem["brix"].Font.Bold = true;

                }
                if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem["temp"].Text) > 91 || float.Parse(dataBoundItem["temp"].Text) < 89)
                {
                    dataBoundItem["temp"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    dataBoundItem["temp"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    dataBoundItem["temp"].Font.Bold = true;

                }
                if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem["bud"].Text) > 41.76 || float.Parse(dataBoundItem["bud"].Text) < 3.121)
                {
                    dataBoundItem["bud"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    dataBoundItem["bud"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    dataBoundItem["bud"].Font.Bold = true;

                }
                if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem["cell_count"].Text) > 177.70 || float.Parse(dataBoundItem["cell_count"].Text) < 41.24)
                {
                    dataBoundItem["cell_count"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    dataBoundItem["cell_count"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    dataBoundItem["cell_count"].Font.Bold = true;

                }
                if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem["viability"].Text) > 69.183 || float.Parse(dataBoundItem["viability"].Text) < 5.65)
                {
                    dataBoundItem["viability"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    dataBoundItem["viability"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    dataBoundItem["viability"].Font.Bold = true;

                }
                if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem["dp4"].Text) > 10.892 || float.Parse(dataBoundItem["dp4"].Text) < 2.556)
                {
                    dataBoundItem["dp4"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    dataBoundItem["dp4"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    dataBoundItem["dp4"].Font.Bold = true;

                }
                if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem["dp3"].Text) > 6.052 || float.Parse(dataBoundItem["ph"].Text) < 1.412)
                {
                    dataBoundItem["bud"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    dataBoundItem["bud"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    dataBoundItem["bud"].Font.Bold = true;

                }
                if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem["maltose"].Text) > 8.285 || float.Parse(dataBoundItem["maltose"].Text) < .419)
                {
                    dataBoundItem["maltose"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    dataBoundItem["maltose"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    dataBoundItem["maltose"].Font.Bold = true;

                }
                if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem["glucose"].Text) > 6.695 || float.Parse(dataBoundItem["glucose"].Text) < -0.263)
                {
                    dataBoundItem["glucose"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    dataBoundItem["glucose"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    dataBoundItem["glucose"].Font.Bold = true;

                }
                if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"].Text) > .124 || float.Parse(dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"].Text) < .0101)
                {
                    dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    dataBoundItem["lactic_acid"].Font.Bold = true;

                }
                if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem["glycerol"].Text) > .574 || float.Parse(dataBoundItem["ph"].Text) < .332)
                {
                    dataBoundItem["glycerol"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    dataBoundItem["glycerol"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    dataBoundItem["glycerol"].Font.Bold = true;

                }
                if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"].Text) > 0.176|| float.Parse(dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"].Text) < -.0756)
                {
                    dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    dataBoundItem["acetic_acid"].Font.Bold = true;

                }
                if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem["ethanol"].Text) > 1.159 || float.Parse(dataBoundItem["ethanol"].Text) < .0053)
                {
                    dataBoundItem["ethanol"].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    dataBoundItem["ethanol"].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    dataBoundItem["ethanol"].Font.Bold = true;

                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This would have been a good Code Review question: http://code review.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

All of your if statements are doing the same thing, you can refactor them into a method.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    //Is it a GridDataItem
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        //Get the instance of the right type
        GridDataItem dataBoundItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;

        //Check the formatting condition
        if (dataBoundItem["sample_hour"].Text == "4hr YP")
        {
            SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["ph"], 5.72, 4.75);
            SetFormatting(dataBoundItem["brix"], 22.36, 17.35);

            // etc...
        }

    }
}

private void SetFormatting(TableCell cell, float minValue, float maxValue)
{
    float value = float.Parse(cell.Text);

    if (value > minValue || value < maxValue)
    {
        cell.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        cell.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        cell.Font.Bold = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank your this works perfect is much cleaner. Just out of curiosity is there a easy why to get the min and max values from a class within a entity model?

Comment: I have this entity class and the min and max will be the val_hi and val_lo and there is a row for ph,brix, etc.
    public partial class tbl_ferm_validation
    {
        public int validation_id { get; set; }
        public string sample_type { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> val_hi { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> val_hihi { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> val_lo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> val_lolo { get; set; }
       }
    }

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking. You can get your entity class from the e.Item.DataItem property. var item = e.Item.DataItem as tbl_ferm_validation;

Comment: Good morning, I am get an exception and the                float value = float.Parse(cellText); for input string was not in a correct format. The input is a float ex. 6.53. What could this be if the the value is null that will be fine right?

Comment: If cell.Text is null you'll get a ArgumentNullException. See docs here: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I am get a formatexception the values are in a sql table with a datatype decimal(18,3).

Comment: The cell text is not in the valid format if you are getting a format exception. Use your debugger to see what the value of cell.Text is and try and figure out what's going on. You can also look into [float.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to validate your cell text value

Answer (score 1):

The logic in the if's is identical, so - move that out into a method of it's own:

```
private void Logic( GridDataItem dataBoundItem, string key, float max, float min )
{
    float f = float.Parse( dataBoundItem[key].Text );
    if( f > max || f < min )
    {
         dataBoundItem[key].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
         dataBoundItem[key].ForeColor = Color.Black;
         dataBoundItem[key].Font.Bold = true;
    }
}
```

Then use like so:

```
Logic( dataBoundItem, "ph", 5.72, 4.75 );
Logic( dataBoundItem, "brix", 22.36, 17.35 );
...
```

But then, you still have your data mixed with your logic. So, create a class that holds the data for you (i.e. key, max, min, etc). Add a bunch of instances of that class to an array/list, and loop through it running your logic on each one:

```
class Rule
{
    public string Key;
    public float Min, Max;
}

private Rule[] m_RulesCase1 = new Rule[]
                              {
                                  new Rule() { Key = "ph", Max = 5.72, Min = 4.75 }
                                  new Rule() { Key = "brix", Max = 22.36, Min = 17.35 }
                                  ...
                              };

private void ApplyRule( GridDataItem dataBoundItem, Rule r )
{
    float f = float.Parse( dataBoundItem[r.Key].Text );
    if( f > r.Max || f < r.Min )
    {
         dataBoundItem[r.Key].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
         dataBoundItem[r.Key].ForeColor = Color.Black;
         dataBoundItem[r.Key].Font.Bold = true;
    }
}

private void ApplyRules( GridDataItem dataBoundItem, IEnumerable<Rule> rules )
{
    foreach( var r in rules )
        ApplyRule( dataBoundItem, r );
}
```

And, you could always take it further and get the rules from a configuration file or other source, avoiding having it in the code completely.

Comment: How would i go about getting these  values from a database?

Comment: Explaining that takes a lot more space than what I can fit into these comments..! Google and stackoverflow search is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a procedure like this:

```
private void CellFormat(string column,float min,float max,Color backcolor,Color forecolor,bool bold)
{
   if (float.Parse(dataBoundItem[column].Text) > min || float.Parse(dataBoundItem[column].Text) < max5)
   {
                    dataBoundItem[column].BackColor = backcolor;
                    dataBoundItem[column].ForeColor = forecolor;
                    dataBoundItem[column].Font.Bold = bold;
    }
```

}

What would give :

```
CellFormat("ph"  , 4.75, 5.72, Color.Yellow,Color.Black,true) ;
CellFormat("brix",17.35,22.36, Color.Yellow,Color.Black,true) ;
```